# How can I pass value to the model with calculating in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have a model, it has 'id_number(integer)' and 'date(string)',  I have:

```
<%= f.label :date %>
<%= f.text_field :date %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

I want to get this date(string) and save it as 'id_number' in integer to the model. How can I achieve this by ruby on rails?

Comment: so you want to convert date to integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `before_save` [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to handle this.

```
class YourModelClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :date_to_id_number

  def date_to_id_number
    #code that converts date to id_number
  end
end
```